# PHP 5.2, Ubuntu 10.04 LTS truncates external input vars

Tags: ubuntu, php, ubuntu-10.04

Why does PHP 5.2 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS truncate large number $_POST (external input) vars, like the max_input_vars directive in PHP 5.3?

I am supporting an old e-commerce site (that is soon to be replaced) and after recently updating, the admin could no longer fully edit a product due to the having over 1000 input vars.

(PHP 5.2 was installed using the [Zend Server Community Edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/))

Comment: I searched and debugged for quite a while to find out that is was the `max_input_vars` directive.  But, officially, there is no `max_input_vars` directive in PHP 5.2, according to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php).

I finally found that it was back-ported [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.22).   

Updating/adding the directive solved the problem.

I hope this helps save someone else the headache of tracking this down.

Comment: Could you post that as an answer instead of a comment, then accept the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Posted as an answer.  (I did not understand when I posted the question that I would have to wait 8 hours to post the answer, so I put the answer as a comment, so no one would waste time trying to figure it out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched and debugged for quite a while to find out that is was the `max_input_vars` directive.  But, officially, there is no `max_input_vars` directive in PHP 5.2, according to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php).

I finally found that it was back-ported [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.22).

Updating/adding the directive solved the problem.

I hope this helps save someone else the headache of tracking this down.